# add a student after a small verification in cakephp

Tags: cakephp

I have two tables in the database: a class table and the other student.
Then, I want to add a student after a small verification.
so I have a button named "add student" in the index of the class,  when I click this boutton  first i want to check the number of the class entered by keyboard with the other numbers found in the database.
 if it exists then retrieve the id of the class to pass at the view of add student else an error message and remains in the same view.

I tried to do and all the correct code but still displays an error message that says the number is not identical with that I sue the number exists.

in controller :

```
 public function admin_verif_show() {

    $this->set('title_for_layout', __('verification'));
    $this->Class->recursive = 0;

  //***************all number class in data base************//
        $nums= $this->Class->find('list', array(
         'fields' => array(
         'Class.num',
           ),

           ));    
  //*******************************************************//
        if (!empty($this->request->data)) { 

          $num= $this->request->data['Class']['num'];

          foreach ($nums as $nu) {
            if ( $num == $nu) {  
             $id= $this->request->data['Class']['id'];

             $this->redirect(array('controller'=>'students','action' => 'add',$id));

                 }else{

                $this->Session->setFlash(__('le num n"est pas identique, essayer une autre fois'), 'default', array('class' => 'error'));

                $this->redirect(array('action' => 'verif_show'));
                 } 
                  }
                }
   }
```

Comment: please any idea for my problem

Comment: PLEAAAAAAAAAAAAAAASE HELP ME

Answer (score 0):

did u try debugging?

```
$num= $this->request->data['Class']['num'];

debug($num);
debug($nums);
die();
```

It's hard to answer this question without knowing whats in the variables...

Perhaps $num simply isn't in $nums?

Perhaps $num is a string and $nums are integers?

So you have to provide at least the debug info, that someone can help you.

Comment: result for $nums : array(
 (int) 23 => '07/2015',
 (int) 25 => '02/2015',
 (int) 26 => '03/2015',
 (int) 30 => '13/2015',
 (int) 31 => '13/2015',
 (int) 32 => '04/2015'
)

Comment: result for $num is null

Comment: so $num is a null pointer, that means "$num= $this->request->data['Class']['num'];" isn't set ... so you have to debug($this->request->data) to see what you actually get inside the action...

Answer (score 0):

From the looks of it you can greatly simplify your code. There seems to be no reason to loop over all the classes. Instead, if someone's submitted a number just check if that exists in the database or not:-

```
public function admin_verif_show() {
    $this->set('title_for_layout', __('verification'));
    $this->Class->recursive = 0;

    if (!empty($this->request->data['Class']['num'])) {
        if ($this->Class->findByNum($this->request->data['Class']['num'])) {
            $id = $this->request->data['Class']['id'];
            return $this->redirect(array('controller' => 'students', 'action' => 'add', $id));
        } else {
            $this->Session->setFlash(__('le num n"est pas identique, essayer une autre fois'), 'default', array('class' => 'error'));
            return $this->redirect(array('action' => 'verif_show'));
        }
    }

    return;
}
```

Also, you should remember to return after doing a redirect. This is to ensure that the code after the redirect doesn't run (mainly for when using tests, but good practice anyway).

Comment: also i change the code `public function admin_verif_show() {   
    $this->set('title_for_layout', __('verification'));
    $this->Class->recursive = 0;        
        if (!empty($this->request->data)) {   
            if ( $this->Class->findBynum($this->request->data['Class']['num'])) {  $id= $this->request->id;
             $this->redirect(array('controller'=>'students','action' => 'add',$id)); } else{ $this->Session->setFlash(__('le num du marché n"est pas identique, essayer une autre fois'), 'default', array('class' => 'error'));$this->redirect(array('action' => 'verif_show',$id));} }}`

Comment: always this message "le num du marché n"est pas identique, essayer une autre fois" which means that the number does not exist

Comment: @HelaBriki is this working for you, or is it still failing unexpectedly?

Comment: Not sure why you've added the extra conditional to check `!empty($this->request->id)`. If `!empty($this->request->data['Class']['num'])` is returning `false` then there's your problem. You need to check what `$this->request->data` is returning. Try using `debug($this->request->data);` to see what the array looks like. I suspect your indexes aren't what you expect.